# Why a module in my multi-module maven project doesn't work?

Tags: java, git, eclipse, maven

I fetched a project from a remote repo. As a result, I have a project with 3 modules that work fine and one module that somehow is not a part of the project or something.
Here is the screenshot of my project:
[image]

So anagram, calculator and char counter work well, but java-8-api does not.

Here is the root pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.foxminded</groupId>
    <artifactId>foxminded-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>anagram</module>
        <module>calculator</module>
        <module>char-counter</module>
        <module>java-8-api</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                <version>2.23.4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is the java-8-api pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.foxminded</groupId>
    <artifactId>foxminded-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>java-8-api</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the pom.xml of `java-8-api`? Does an error occur? If so, can you please share it?

Comment: I added java-8-api file too. What kind of error? I get no errors cause I cannot launch the code..

Comment: please clarify what do you mean by "does not work well" ?is it about compilation ? run ? import ?

Comment: How did you import it in eclipse? Have you tried Alt+F5?

Comment: Right-click the parent project and choose _Configure > Configure and Detect Nested Projects..._.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Right-click the parent/root project** and choose ***Configure > Configure and Detect Nested Projects...***